# Why was there a zmq error, if setting a value of a protobuf serializable class?

Tags: c++11, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I am testing a code that uses zmq as socket and networking tool, and protobuf for serialization.

The code receives a zmq_message and parses it to a protobuf class, in return I change the value of one of the class members and send the same class back to the requestor.

Somehow during this process a zmq assertion `check()` fails. I don't really know why it is happening as everything looks okay to me.

The code looks like this in the main file:

```
zmq::socket_t external(context, ZMQ_REP);
external.bind("tcp://*:29067");

zmq::message_t request;
external.recv(&request);
msg.deserialize(request);

msg.set_probed_value(12.0);
zmq::message_t response = msg.serialize();
external.send(response);
```

deserialize method looks like this.

```
_msg.ParseFromString(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(msg.data()));
```

and serialize method as below:

```
zmq::message_t request(_msg.ByteSize());
std::string value = _msg.SerializeAsString();
memcpy(request.data(), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(value.c_str()), value.size());
return request;
```

and **`set_probed_value()`** looks like this:

```
void set_probed_value(const double& val)
{
    _msg.clear_probed();
    _msg.set_probed(val);
}
```

I know for a fact that problem is caused when I set the valued of probed to a different number than what it was set at parse time. If I remove that line `msg.set_probed_value(12.0)`, no exception happens and everything is okay.

> Assertion failed: check () (/apps/zmq/libzmq/src/msg.cpp:347)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Suspect? Violating the ZeroMQ API published principles

**All message manipulations are know to be rather fragile.**

What about doing an explicit content-copy first, instead of a just syntax sugared `reinterpret_cast<...>( msg.data() )` content ( referenced by a ZeroMQ delivered pointer ) being directly manipulated?

> ***Avoid modifying message content*** after a message has been copied with `zmq_msg_copy()`, **doing so can result in undefined behaviour**. If what you need is an actual hard copy, allocate a new message using `zmq_msg_init_size()` and copy the message content using `memcpy()`.

An explicit `close()` of a `request` message object is also advised, right after the safe content-copy has been made, as a published fair design practice in the published ZeroMQ API strongly recommends.

> *Never access `zmq_msg_t` members directly, instead always use the `zmq_msg` family of functions.*

ZeroMQ API is **explicitly warning not to attempt to manipulate any message content** in any other manner, than using the API-published functions / methods. Better avoid any such tricks, even at a cost of a bit more lengthy code and a few more SLOC-s.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a NULL termination in that zmq message `msg`?

`_msg.ParseFromString(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(msg.data()));`

If not this will fill your `_msg` with garbage as it reads past the end what you think is a string.

The reason I ask is:

When you create/send the message you **do not include the NULL**

```
zmq::message_t request(_msg.ByteSize());
std::string value = _msg.SerializeAsString();
memcpy(request.data(), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(value.c_str()), value.size());
return request;
```